# jquery ui drag drop show position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am a newbie to jQuery UI. I have gone through jQuery sortable and connect-lists where I can drag elements from one side to another and make them sortable.Upto this point I have finished. But here I want that when I will make drop one element from one to another container and made drop then that should show the elements position i.e left,top position. Also after each drop it should show the elements name which are inside List A and List B.

Here is working demo of [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RmLAA/1/)

I had tried to do this. So my code for so far is like this

```
<div name="list-a" class="droppable connectedSortable">
     <h3>List A</h3>

    <div class="task-wrapper">
        <div class="draggable" id="1" name="1"> <a href="#">Element 1</a>

        </div>
        <div class="draggable" id="2" name="3"> <a href="#">Element 2</a>

        </div>
        <div class="draggable" id="3" name="3"> <a href="#">Element 3</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div name="list-b" class="droppable connectedSortable">
     <h3>List B</h3>

    <div class="task-wrapper">
        <div class="draggable" id="5" name="5"> <a href="#">Element 5</a>

        </div>
        <div class="draggable" id="6" name="6"> <a href="#">Element 6</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".droppable>div").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable>div"
    }).disableSelection();
    $(".draggable").on('drop', function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
   console.log('Left:'+relX+ 'Right:'+relY);
});
});
</script>
```

It is doing drag and drop with sortable. But it is not showing the position and the list item in the conatiners.
So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how it can be done:

```
var parent;
var parentEl;
$(function () {
    $(".droppable>div").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable>div",
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            parent = ui.item.parent().parent().attr('name');
            parentEl = ui.item.parent();
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            if(parent != ui.item.parent().parent().attr('name')){
                alert('top: '+ui.item.position().top);
                alert('left: '+ui.item.position().left);
                alert('for '+parent);
                parentEl.children('div').each(function(){
                    alert($(this).attr('name'));    
                });
                alert('for '+ui.item.parent().parent().attr('name'));
                ui.item.parent().children('div').each(function(){
                    alert($(this).attr('name'));    
                });

            }
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wYx9/

just a FYI

you did have one little typo in your html that name of your `Element 2` was `3` instead of `2` I fixed this in the example above.

```
<div class="draggable" id="2" name="3"> <a href="#">Element 2</a>
```

Comment: @NewUser Please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks